# Use alternate authentication in twisted's Perspective Broker

Tags: python, authentication, hash, cryptography, twisted

I am using twisted's Perspective Broker for a network application. I encountered the problem that it automatically uses an MD5 challenge-response scheme for authentication. Ideally I would prefer not to store MD5 hashes on the server-side due to a number of security vulnerabilities. Alternatively, scrypt, bcrypt or pbkdf2 provide more secure algorithms.

However, while these algorithms are readily available in python, I don't quite see, whether it is possible to implement a custom authentication scheme using the Perspective Broker. Judging from the source, it looks like MD5 is very tightly integrated within the system.

So my question goes to more experienced twisted users: is there a way to use a custom authentication scheme without having to rewrite the whole thing?

(Also, please correct me, if any of my assumptions about twisted or cryptography are wrong. I am quite new to both.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do in order to implement a custom authentication scheme for Perspective Broker is to implement a set of method calls on a root object which, after completion, provide access to your desired application-level object.

You won't be able to re-use PB's built-in [`login`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.spread.pb.PBClientFactory.html#login) method and its accompanying wire-protocol messages, but that's fine; that's the thing you intend to replace anyway :).

Note that [when you construct a `PBServerFactory`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.spread.pb.PBServerFactory.html#__init__), you provide a *root object*.  If you want to call methods on that object, rather than performing a "standard" PB login and calling methods on the returned avatar (i.e. per-user / per-connection object), [call `getRootObject`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.spread.pb.PBClientFactory.html#getRootObject) on the PB client factory and use `callRemote` on the result.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. Somehow I had the impression that it would be worth to re-use all the cred stuff like portals, avatars and realms.

Comment: You can still re-use portals, avatars, and realms, within your own authentication implementation; and in fact, I would recommend that you do.  They're all very abstract though (if they can work with IMAP - and they do - they can certainly work with a slightly modified PB).

Comment: Just wrap your new root object around a `Portal` and implement a new `ICredentials` provider, and you should be all set.

Comment: Hm... I fail to see how the new root object has to call the portal's methods. I tried to implement `NewRoot.remote_login(self, user, pw)` calling `Portal.login` adding a callback to that and returning the resulting `Deferred`. But on the client-side I only get an `Unpersistable`. I assume, `remote_...` methods are not supposed to return `Deferred`s, are they?

Comment: Eventually I ended up not using the cred system after all. Did not seem worth the trouble for my use case.

Comment: That's too bad, because more people using cred means more expertise in building good abstractions for separating out authentication from application logic, but using cred is entirely optional; structure your application as it makes sense to you.

Comment: Well, I do understand your concern. However, I felt that cred was imposing too tight constraints on my application for now. Although I might get back to this issue at some point and see if I can figure out how this is supposed to work.