# Client Authentication using Twisted Perspective Broker with TLS

Tags: python, ssl, twisted, perspective, broker

I am trying to create a server/client using Twisted's Perspective Broker.  I wanted to use TLS for client authentication to identify who is the one connecting.

I found the following links:
http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/ssl.html

[Use TLS and Python for authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677455/use-tls-and-python-for-authentication)

However both are addressing a Protocol.  I don't see how you can get the client identity through Perspective Broker.  Finally, I saw:

[Use alternate authentication in twisted's Perspective Broker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959226/use-alternate-authentication-in-twisteds-perspective-broker)

However, that mentions to call upon the Root Object.  Does that mean I am not able to use Avatar/IPerspective then?  Even if I go the route of using pb.Referencable and server is the one managing the user object, how does the remote_foo() function obtain client identity from the certificate?

Update:  I solved my issue switching over to Twisted AMP and then since I have access to the transport, solved my issue in that manner.  However I would like to know if this is possible in Perspective Broker and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

[`IPBRoot.rootObject(...)`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.5.0/api/twisted.spread.pb.IPBRoot.html#rootObject) is passed a `Broker`.  A `Broker` is a protocol.

At the specific moment in time that `rootObject` is called, the transport isn't initialized yet.  However, if you were to implement a remote method on that object, say, `remote_authenticateUsingTLS`, by the time the protocol is responding to that method, it has a transport and that transport will have a certificate.  So, in your `IPBRoot`'s `rootObject` method, construct an object that remembers the `broker` it was passed, and then in `remote_authenticateUsingTLS`, you can use `Certificate.peerFromTransport(self.broker.transport)` to get the certificate from the peer using their broker.

Hope this helps!